# Load view and make json data available in ajax request (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I want ajax request to load view as well as make json data available for same loaded view. In bellow ajax request, I am making request to `letUsKnow` method which loads views and also I want json data to be available in same loaded views. I tried following code but its not working.

```
$(document).on("click", "#letKnow", function(){
        $.ajax({
        'type': "POST",
        'url': base_url + "init/letUsKnow",    //calling method in controller
        'data': {},
        success: function (response)
        {
            $("#ads_container").html(response.html);
            alert(response.data[0].model_name);     //undefined
        },
        complete: function()
        {

        }
    });
});
```

### init (controller)

```
 public function letUsKnow() {
    $models = $this->dbmodel->get_models();
    $data = json_encode($models);
    $this->load->view("letUsKnow",$data);

}
```

Can this functionality be obtained from single ajax request. I can do with two ajax request that after loading view from one ajax request and again another ajax to request json data. But, How to fulfill this with single ajax request.

### Edit

You can turn the whole response into json.

`$this->load->view()` has a third argument that lets you return the view as  a string to a variable.

I don't understand why you are json encoding `$models` to pass into the view so I will assume you want that as part of the main response

PHP

```
 public function letUsKnow() {
    $models = $this->dbmodel->get_models();

    $output = array(
        'html'=>$this->load->view("letUsKnow",$models, true),
        'data' = >$models
    );
    // should set Content Type header for json here - see output docs
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

### array ($models)

```
 // $models after json encode in ajax response
     {"abc":[{"id":"76","brand_id":"23","model_name":"iphone 4"},{"id":"77","brand_id":"23","model_name":"iphone 4s"}]}

 // after making array of views and data and after json encode in ajax response I get:
      {"html":"this is html views <\/div>\r\n<\/div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
       "data":{"abc":[{"id":"76","brand_id":"23","model_name":"iphone 4"},{"id":"77","brand_id":"23","model_name":"iphone 4s"}]}} 

 // but in real my view's html is:
      <div>this is html views</div><div id="iop"></div>    //html in controller

 // also when I tried to access json object like:
      response.hm   // I get undefined
      response.data.model_name    //I get undefined.
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "init/letUsKnow", //calling method in controller
    data: {},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var modelsData = response.data;             //undefined
        $("#ads_container").html(response.html);    //undefined
    },
    error: function(){ alert('Ooops ... server problem'); }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the whole response into json.

`$this->load->view()` has a third argument that lets you return the view as  a string to a variable.

I don't understand why you are json encoding `$models` to pass into the view so I will assume you want that as part of the main response

PHP

```
 public function letUsKnow() {
    $models = $this->dbmodel->get_models();
    $data = ?? ; // why is it json_encoded?
    $output = array(
        'html'=>$this->load->view("letUsKnow",$data, true),
        'data' = >$models
    );
    // should set Content Type header for json here - see output docs
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "init/letUsKnow", //calling method in controller
    data: {},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var modelsData = response.data;
        $("#ads_container").html(response.html);
    },
    error: function(){ alert('Ooops ... server problem'); }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know view can be assigned to variable. I json encoded `$models` because I need this in view `letUsKnow`. Now, view is also json encoded. I will try and let you know. Thanks for response.

Comment: but `$data` needs to be array when passed to view , then you access the array keys as variables ... or so I always thought in codeigniter. Are you using codeigniter3?

Comment: No I am not using codeigniter 3.0. since its not completed version yet. Okey, but does this functionality accepted in codeigniter below 3.0.\

Comment: yes definitely... I have one project i do a lot of work on and use this approach all the time. Using 2.13

Comment: Its not working. Its throwing error ` json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: type is unsupported, encoded as null`

Comment: That html is meaningless to me. I don't know anything about your view or $models. Concept will work fine , I do it all the time

Comment: Yea I can access that data in view but I cannot access that data in ajax success.

Comment: I can't help much more without being able to see dumps of that data or template.

Comment: I edited my question hope it would helpful for you. I get undefined when access json object in ajax success.

Comment: log the whole response to console, it isn't undefined if success fires and you already showed the array is being converted. zneed to travlers the `data` part properly. It is an array inside `reseponse.data.abc` ...there is no `response.data.model_name ` in that structure. You would have to loop over array of objects to access the `model_name`

Answer (score 1):

```
    //PHP
    public function letUsKnow() {
        $models = $this->dbmodel->get_models();
    $data =[];// why is it json_encoded?
            header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        $output = array(
            'html'=>$this->load->view("letUsKnow",$data, true),
            'data' = >$models
        );
        // should set Content Type header for json here - see output docs
        echo json_encode($output);
return;
    }


    //AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "init/letUsKnow", //calling method in controller
        data: {},
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var modelsData = response.data;
            $("#ads_container").html(response.html);
        },
        error: function(){ alert('Ooops ... server problem'); }
    });
```